# não diferenciar maiúsculas e minusculas na URL

Tags: apache, htaccess

em minha página, tenho várias imagens e a forma que esta escrita no caminho tem maiúsculo e minusculo, por exemplo, `<img src="imagens/ImagemSistemaDepartamento.JPG">`

precisava que de alguma forma que `.htacess` leia o meu código e independente maiúsculo e minusculo, encontre a imagem, pois ela existe no diretório.

obrigado.

Comment: Seria melhor consertar os nomes. Além de ficar mais portátil, a aplicação vai ficar conceitualmente correta. Nada que um _search & replace_ bem feito não resolva.

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco. Mas será que não tem uma configuração que permita que .htacess ignore ?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode facilmente fazer o *apache* ignorar a [caixa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caixa_alta_e_caixa_baixa) usando o módulo [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html), que faz parte dos módulos padrão, mas precisa ser ativado.

Ative o módulo, reinicie o *apache* e adicione no `.htaccess`:

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Fonte: [How do I make URLs case insensitive in Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14814577/2932525)

Comment: É uma solução para o problema. Vale comentar que há uma queda de performance, que pode fazer diferença em aplicações mais pesadas/acessadas, pois o Apache tem que escanear o diretório para achar candidatos ao URL, caso não seja idêntico ao nome do recurso desejado. Mas como o que o autor pede é isso, +1 na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC]

</IfModule>
```